# If statement within while no showing empty tag

Tags: php, if-statement, search, mysqli, while-loop

Building a custom site for non-profit. Have a hang up on the search page.

Here is what I have...

It shows results but does not show anything for empty results. I can not figure this one out.

```
while($rowitem = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) 
    {

         If (empty($results))  
          {    

       echo 'NO RESULTS';


          }
         Else
         {
            echo  "<div>"; .....
```

There is a lot of code past this that works.

I appreciate any help that anyone can provide. I am sure it is something simple that I am screwing up.

Answer (score 1):

while loop will not run in case of empty results so you need to check before while:

```
if(empty($results)){
    echo 'NO RESULTS';
else{
    while($rowitem = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        /* your code here */
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and intergrated into my code
 I am still missing something

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
$sname = $_POST["srch"];

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `members` Where lname = '$sname' ";
            $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}

if(empty($results))
    echo 'NO RESULTS';
 
 else{
      while($rowitem = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

The page loads and says "NO RESULT" however after the search is done it will show results if there are any and nothing if there are not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the number of rows that are in the result set first with [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php), checking that `$results` is empty doesn't have the same effect (it may be `false` which means your SQL failed to run)...

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($results)){
    echo 'NO RESULTS';
else{
    while($rowitem = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        /* your code here */
    }
}
```